# Is it possible to redirect user input to determine "choices" (user input options) of a second user input?

Tags: r, shiny, user-input

I am creating a shiny dashboard and am trying to redirect user input to determine "choices" (user input options) of a second user input. I am loading a csv file that contains the data that the user input will be dependent on:

Example: One column of the csv contains a customer number. Sometimes there are repeating customer numbers because that customer is present in multiple states (therefore there is a customer number in 2 different rows linked to two different states)

If said customer number is picked in the first user input, how would I use that input to create the 2 state options in the second user input drop-down?

I have attached my code:

```
bcl <- read.csv("C:/Users/jtberg/Desktop/rand_data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("UW Model Output"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput("customername", "Customer Name",
                  choices = sort(unique(bcl$Customer_Name))),
      #starting second version with dependent input variable choices
      uiOutput("secondSelection")

    ),
    mainPanel(("Results"),
            textOutput("customername"),
            textOutput("secondSelection"))
  )
)
)
server <- function(input, output){
  #output$columns <- renderUI({
    #n <- input$customername
    #myspecies <- bcl[(bcl$Quintiles == n),11]
    #mydata = get(myspecies)
    #selectInput('pstate', 'Policy State', choices = names(mydata))
  output$secondSelection <- renderUI({
    selectInput("pstate", "Maybe: ", choices = as.character(bcl[bcl$Customer_Name == input$customername, "name"]))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Portion 2: 
If I were to want and use the user input to create a dynamic table display such that when choosing the customer number and state, all of the contents from the rest of that corresponding row (where the customer number and state are) are displayed in a data table, how would I do so?

Example: 
             (User Input Columns)

```
    |      Col 1     |  Col 2     |  Col 3   |    Col 4   |    Col 5 | 
    ------------------------------------------------------------------            
    |   CusNumInput | StateInput |    A     |      B     |      C   |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

User input is (CusNumInput and StateInput) therefore print a table with A, B and C in it.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible to do. Since I couldn't access your data set, I had to create my own.

The key to it is making your dataset for the filter be dependent on the previous choice.

I also added a conditional feature for your second filter as a bonus, you may want to remove it for your needs.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  #
  titlePanel("UW Model Output"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("firstSelection"),
      uiOutput("secondSelection")
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output){

  dat <- data.frame(CustomerNumber = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5), State = c("AZ","FL","IL","AZ","NC","IN","WI", "CO"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  output$firstSelection <- renderUI ({
       selectInput(inputId = "First", "First Filter",
                   choices = c("",paste0(sort(as.character(unique(dat$CustomerNumber)))))
    )
  })

  output$secondSelection <- renderUI ({
      Lvl2 <- dat[dat$CustomerNumber == input$First,]

      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.First != ''",
        selectInput(inputId = "Second", "Second Filter",
                  choices = paste0(sort(unique(Lvl2$State)))
                  )
        )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

***Updated***

```
library (DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  #
  titlePanel("UW Model Output"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("firstSelection"),
      uiOutput("secondSelection")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table1")
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output){

  dat <- data.frame(CustomerNumber = c(1,1,1,2,2), 
                    State = c("AZ","FL","IL","AZ","NC"), 
                    Col3 = c("B","D","C","E","F"),
                    Col4 = c("G","H","I","J","K"),
                    Col5 = c("L","M","N","O","P"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  #Fitler Selections
  output$firstSelection <- renderUI ({
    selectInput(inputId = "First", "First Filter",
                choices = c("",paste0(sort(as.character(unique(dat$CustomerNumber)))))
    )
  })

  output$secondSelection <- renderUI ({
    Lvl2 <- dat[dat$CustomerNumber == input$First,]

    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.First != ''",
                     selectInput(inputId = "Second", "Second Filter",
                                 choices = paste0(sort(unique(Lvl2$State)))
                     )
    )
  })

  #Data Table
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    temp <- dat[dat$CustomerNumber == input$First & dat$State == input$Second,]
    temp <- temp[-c(1:2)]


  },
  rownames = FALSE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to help! Make sure you hit the checkmark that I solved your answer so other people know there's an available answer.

Comment: If i were to want to find the row number for the user input selections could I do this? Essentially I would want to use that row number to acquire values in that same row but in different columns!

Comment: Could you update your post to include an example of this? Are your rows unique? Your original statement said you have duplicate customer numbers.

Comment: yes i do have duplicate customer numbers so i would want to take customer number and policy state into account when searching for the rows where both of these match the user input and then print out the rest of the columns in that row.

Comment: Updated with your new request